# Converting all document types(MS DOCs+TIFFs+JPGs) stored on Filenet CE to pdf

Tags: java, ms-word, itext, apache-poi, filenet-p8

Currently we are developing a Java application to grab documents (all types can be stored on filenet) from *`Filenet`* and displaying it in pdf format, the issue is that I need a tool for converting all `MS` doc types (doc, docx, ppt, pptx,...) to pdf. I've tried *`Apache POI`* and *`iText`* but they just convert the Office 2007 formats and it just gets a plain text without any formatting and without images.

Second in image documents I already converted the images to pdf but I need to get the annotations made by IBM applet image viewer printed on the image. How can I get that?

I need to an opensource/free solution, any not-free solution (like *`Snowbound`*, *`adptel`*) will be rejected by the customer.

Any support will be appreciated

Comment: When you found that (or written it) let us know.

Comment: ok @EugenRieck, it seems a very hard task.

Comment: Would using OpenOffice (called from Java by something like JODConverter) work for your use case?

Comment: @Gagravarr its work, but it would be better if i gonna not using it

Comment: Or, if that would fit into your Filenet architecture, you can use Filenet Rendition Engine which automatically transforms all uploaded documents to PDF (or HTML).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out docx4java, http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j

Can handle .docx and .pptx exports and the documentation gives some info on how to handle older .doc files.